# Draw 9Patch image without changing actual design

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have *.png image. Using this image , I am creating 9 patch image. 
In *.png image , there are 45 degree lines.When I Stretch this image, 9 patch Image showing horizontal lines . 
I want 45 degree lines in 9 patch image. Can u please suggest the way for creating right 9 patch image ?

Comment: 45 degrees lines are not compatible with nine patch images

Comment: @ Luksprog : I didnt get u ? we can not create image with 45 degree lines in 9 patch ?

Comment: Not possible with 9 patch, consider drawing at run time using `canvas` and `paint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9-patch is not really the right tool for diagonal lines.  Maybe you should consider using a [tiled background](http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-tile-background-image-in-android.html) instead?

Answer (score 2):

The 9 patch will not allow you to draw continuous 45 degree lines.  You can define an area or range for a stretch region, but as the region stretches it will change the angle of the line from 45 for that area.

You are likely getting continuous horizontal or vertical lines because only one pixel or very narrow area is able to stretch.

Comment: It Helps me to understand basic problem.Thank you.